# Kendo TabStrip Jquery not working

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-tabstrip

So I am trying to dynamically add some content to a Kendo TabStrip through JavaScript. The code Im using to get the Jquery object is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $tabStrip = $("#tabStrip");
    alert(JSON.stringify($tabStrip));        
    $kendoTabStrip = $tabStrip.kendoTabStrip();
    alert(JSON.stringify($kendoTabStrip));
    $data = $kendoTabStrip.data("kendoTabStrip");
    alert(JSON.stringify($data));
});
```

This would synthetize to

```
$tabstrip=$('$tabStrip".kendoTabStrip().data("kendoTabStrip")
```

However, when I call an append method i get an error. This is why I put the alert to know the value of the tabstrip and each time I am getting "undefined". I do not know what to do.
I appreciate any help.

Greetings,
Luis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get a reference to the TabStrip normally you use:

```
$tabStrip = $("#tabStrip").data("kendoTabStrip");
```

you can also do:

```
$tabStrip = $("#tabStrip").kendoTabStrip().data("kendoTabStrip");
```

Doing this, you can call `append` for appending an additional tab. Example:

```
$tabStrip.append(
    [
        {
            text: "Baiona",
            content: "<h2>N/A</h2><p>Not available</p>"
        }
    ]
);
```

See it in action here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/5rgd7/

NOTE: your `$data` is actually the reference to the `TabStrip` object so using your code you should do `$data.append(...)`.